# Flush saída de dados frontend

Tags: php

Bom estou seguindo o exemplo do **php.net**

```
    <?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
  echo $i . '<br />';
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
?>
```

se eu executa direto esse script no navegador ele conta de 1 a 10 mostrando seu resultado corretamente...

Porem tenho uma textarea que recebe os item , e ajax para enviar o post e busca o resultado na tela de acordo com o resultado

mais quando eu envio os item, o flush não funciona só me retorna o resultado no fim do for

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enviar").click(function() {
        var nome = $("#nome");
        var nomePost = nome.val(); 
        $.post("flush.php", {nome: nomePost},
        function(data){
         $("#resposta").html(data);
         }
         , "html");
    });
});
</script>



    <form action="" method="post">
      <textarea name="nome" id="nome" cols="45" rows="5"  required placeholder="Sua lista bla bla bla bla..."></textarea>
      <br /> 
      <br />
     </form>
     <button id="enviar" type="submit" class="ls-btn-primary ls-btn-xs">Check !</button>
      <br>
    </h6>

<br>

  <div  id="resposta"> Aguardando lista!</div>
```

Comment: Talvez onde está 

`var nome = $("#nome");`

Deva estar 

`var nome = $("#nome").attr("name");`

Comment: Olá Wender, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Muito interessante sua pergunta. Mas talvez esteja usando a técnica errada. Se precisar de um mecanismo para enviar dados para o cliente pouco a pouco de forma assíncrona, talvez [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) seja o que você procura. No entanto, se a ideia for exibir algo progressivamente na tela, o cenário muda completamente. Seria melhor explicar melhor o seu intuito. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

O cliente até recebe os dados a cada `flush` supostamente, no entanto o ajax só entrega o resultado final, ou seja o ajax só vai lhe entregar algo quando `readyState` for igual a 4 (equivale a `complete`).

Para receber parte por parte é necessário criar múltiplas requisições usando o metodo GET ou SESSION. Acredito que você irá usar isto com dados reais, no caso adicionei um exemplo apenas para simular a situação, se for banco de dados você pode verificar com `mysqli_num_rows` e `LIMIT ?,?` (offset e limit) se retornou `0`, sendo o resultado igual a zero então você pode usar:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    echo 'final';
    exit;
}
```

Crie um arquivo chamado chunkdata.php

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ?   0 : $_GET['offset'];
$limit  = empty($_GET['limit'])  ?  10 : $_GET['limit'];

if ($offset > 100) {
    //E você pode criar uma fork para limitar as requisições quando chegar ao resultado final, neste caso é apenas um exemplo para simular
    echo 'final';
    exit;
}

for( $i = $offset; $i < $limit; $i++)
{
  echo $i . '<br />';
}
?>
```

E o delay seria no front-end, algo como:

```
function getData(nomePost, offset) {
    var delay = 1000;//Delay das requisições
    var limit = 10;//O limite da consulta será de dez em dez
    offset = offset || 0;//Se for undefined usa 0

    $.post("chunkdata.php?offset=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit,
        {
            "nome": nomePost
        }, function(data) {
            //Se o servidor retornar a palavra "final" então isto irá interromper o loop
            if (data !== "final") {
                 return;
            }
            var lastData = $("#nome").html();
            $("#nome").html(lastData + data);

            //Roda o script novamente
            setTimeout(getData, delay, nomePost, offset);
    }, "html");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#enviar").click(function() {
        getData($("#nome").val());
    });
});
```